# Finding the no of ways to count the letters in an English alphabet

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many strings of six lower case letters from the English
alphabet contain

a) the letter $a$?

b) the letters $a$ and $b$?

c) the letters $a$ and $b$ in consecutive positions with $a$
preceding $b$, with all the letters distinct?

d) the letters $a$ and $b$, where $a$ is somewhere to the left
of $b$ in the string, with all the letters distinct?

**What I tried:**

a) to find the no of ways to get letter $a$, I took

no of ways = 
total no of ways without restriction-does not contain letter $a$

thus no of ways $= 26^6 - 25^6$

b) to find the no of ways to get letters $a$ and $b$, I took

no of ways = 
total no of ways without restriction-(does not contain letter $a$ + does not contain letter $b$)

thus no of ways = $26^6-25^6-25^6$

I'm unsure of how to do part c) and part d). Could anyone explain? Thanks.

Comment: I think $a$ is correct, but $b$ has a double count  of the strings with no a and no b (so think inclusion-exclusion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer for the first part is correct.

> How many strings of six lower case letters from the English alphabet contain the letters $a$ and $b$?

You subtracted the number of strings that do not contain $a$ and the number of strings that do not contain $b$ from the total number of strings to obtain $26^6 - 2 \cdot 25^6$.  However, you have subtracted the strings that contain neither $a$ nor $b$ twice.  Thus, we have to add those $24^6$ strings to the total.  By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of strings that contain both $a$ and $b$ is $$26^6 - 2 \cdot 25^6 + 24^6$$

> How many strings of six distinct lower case letters from the English alphabet contain the letters $a$ and $b$ in consecutive positions with $a$ preceding $b$.

Think of $ab$ as a block.  Since the letters are distinct, we must select four other letters from the remaining $24$ letters, which we can choose in $\binom{24}{4}$ ways. We now have five objects to arrange, the block $ab$ and the four other letters we just selected.  They can be permuted in $5!$ ways.  Hence, the number of strings of six distinct lower case letters from the English alphabet that contain the letters $a$ and $b$ in consecutive positions with $a$ preceding $b$ is $$\binom{24}{4} \cdot 5!$$

> How many strings of six distinct lower case letters from the English alphabet contain the letters $a$ and $b$ with $a$ preceding $b$.

Since the letters are distinct, we must choose $4$ of the remaining $24$ letters, which we can do in $\binom{24}{4}$ ways.  We can arrange those six letters in $6!$.  However, in half of those permutations, $b$ precedes $a$.  Thus, the number of six distinct lower case letters from the English alphabet contain the letters $a$ and $b$ with $a$ preceding $b$ is 
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \binom{24}{4} \cdot 6!$$

Comment: would it be 5 *24C4

Comment: @Pole_Star  If you are referring to the second question, the answer I wrote above is correct.  There are five ways of placing the block $ab$, but we also need to arrange the remaining four letters we have selected in the remaining four positions, which can be done in $4!$ ways.  Note that $5 \cdot 4! = 5!$.  Since there are $\binom{24}{4}$ ways of selecting those four letters, the number of admissible arrangements is $$\binom{24}{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 4! = \binom{24}{4}5!$$